# Spring Boot startup error Cannot invoke "org.apache.commons.logging.Log.isDebugEnabled()" because "this.logger" is null

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot:3.2.1 for kotlin. But when I was using it, suddenly the app startup got an error. I'm in
[Similar issue 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940897/nullpointerexception-in-genericfilterbean-on-spring-boot-application-start-after)
[Similar issue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927054/cannot-invoke-org-apache-commons-logging-log-isdebugenabled-because-this-lo)
But their problem though the stack looks the same. But the timing of the anomaly is different，And I [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Gdl.png)didn't find the corresponding answer under the question

I've googled a lot of similar errors, but none of them matched。I don't understand the debug startup process

Comment: Without some code, configuration this will be impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

it is funny that i had the same question right after you posted this and voted the Q up :)

I am using AOP and there was a typo in `@Pointcut`
it was `@Pointcut("within(com.mypackage..*")` and it should have been `@Pointcut("within(com.mypackage.*")`

Make sure you don't have a silly error like this and good luck

Comment: In my case it was a @Transactional annotation in the filter. But the AOP hint was right on the spot